# Limitar al último movimiento de acuerdo a 2 campos

Tags: sql, postgresql

Tengo una tabla llamada descarga, dicha tabla me guarda es el historial de movimientos de los contenedores bajo el campo **equipo_identi**, para diferenciar que el contenedor no se repita, se agregó un campo llamado **ciclo** para saber cuantas veces el contenedor ha llegado al pais. Tengo el siguiente query, que me muestra los últimos movimientos del contenedor bajo el ciclo máximo:

```
select x.*
from (select des.movimiento, des.equipo_identi, des.status, max(des.ciclo) as ciclo,
        rank() over (order by des.ciclo desc) as rank,
        rank() over (order by primo.prioridad desc) as rnk
      from publico.descarga des 
      inner join publico.prioridad_movimiento primo 
           on des.movimiento = primo.movimiento
      group by des.movimiento, des.equipo_identi, des.status, des.ciclo, primo.prioridad
     ) x
where rank = 1;
```

Y me devuelve, como se observa, es todos los movimientos de (en este caso 2 contenedores) los contenedores en su ciclo máximo(en este caso 2):

```
movimiento   | equipo_identi | status | ciclo | rank | rnk
---------------------------------------------------------
Export       | CSLU1407729   | Full   | 2     |   1  | 1
GateIn Puerto| CSLU1387094   | Empty  | 2     |   1  | 4
GateIn Puerto| CSLU1407729   | Empty  | 2     |   1  | 4
GateOut Patio| CSLU1387094   | Empty  | 2     |   1  | 8
GateOut Patio| CSLU1407729   | Empty  | 2     |   1  | 8
GateIn Patio | CSLU1387094   | Empty  | 2     |   1  | 12
GateIn Patio | CSLU1407729   | Empty  | 2     |   1  | 12
```

Pero necesito solo ver el último movimiento según **equipo_identi**, bajo esto por eso tengo en my query max(des.ciclo), para saber es su último ciclo y no todos los ciclo que haya tenido el mismo, es decir:

```
    movimiento   | equipo_identi | status | ciclo | rank | rnk
    ---------------------------------------------------------
    Export       | CSLU1407729   | Full   | 2     |   1  | 1
    GateIn Puerto| CSLU1387094   | Empty  | 2     |   1  | 4
```

Para determinar el último movimiento, tengo la tabla llamada **prioridad_movimiento** que tiene los campos **prioridad** y **movimiento**.

```
prioridad | movimiento
---------- ----------------
1         | Descarga
2         | GateOut Puerto
3         | GateIn Patio
4         | GateOut Patio
5         | GateIn Puerto
6         | Export
```

Siendo **Export** mi último movimiento y **Descarga** el primer movimiento que tiene que pasar cada campo "equipo_identi"

Comment: ¿Cómo se determina que un movimiento es el ***último***? ¿Puedes explicar el significado de los campos un poco más?

Comment: Claro, lo agrego a mi pregunta.

Comment: Si es posible, lo ideal sería que incluyas como se ven los datos *antes* de aplicarle la consulta. Eso ayuda a entender.

Comment: Estoy tratando de entender mejor tu consulta, pero veo detalles que no cuadran.  Por ejemplo, tienes un `max(des.ciclo)` pero incluyes `des.ciclo` en el `GROUP BY`. Eso no tiene sentido. en lo personal, en vez de asumir que tu consulta está casi correcta y solo necesita una pequeña modificación, preferiría que incluyas un ejemplo de los datos en tus tablas junto con el resultado deseado.  Sospecho que la consulta necesita mas mejoras de lo que se ve a primera vista.

Comment: @sstan Agregaré mas detalles a la pregunta.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simplemente necesitas agregar una condición extra en el `rank() OVER()`. Prueba lo siguiente:

```
select x.*
from (select des.movimiento, des.equipo_identi, des.status, max(des.ciclo) as ciclo,
        rank() over (partition by des.equipo_identi order by des.ciclo desc, primo.prioridad desc) as rank,
        rank() over (order by primo.prioridad desc) as rnk
      from publico.descarga des 
      inner join publico.prioridad_movimiento primo 
           on des.movimiento = primo.movimiento
      group by des.movimiento, des.equipo_identi, des.status, des.ciclo, primo.prioridad
     ) x
where rank = 1;
```

Comment: Me sigue mostrando todos los campos agregando el **partition by** como muestra la primera tabla en mi pregunta

Comment: Pues esto es porque @sstan tiene razón. Cómo se definel el último movimiento?

Comment: ya actualicé mi respuesta

Comment: Agregando el order by de la prioridad me muestra es el último movimiento 'Export' de **equipo_identi** pero de un ciclo anterior.

Comment: @Jorge Entonces da vuelta las condiciones de `ORDER BY`, ya lo cambién en la respuesta. Pero la próxima vez sería bueno que agregues todas las condiciones desde el principio en la pregunta

Comment: Listo, está solucionado, muchas gracias @Lamak era agregar el partition y cambiar el orden del order by. Disculpas por no aclarar bien la pregunta.

Comment: @Jorge no te preocupes. Lo importante es ir aprendiendo para las próximas veces

Answer (score 0):

Ahora que finalmente digerí la pregunta, me doy cuenta de dos cosas:

1. Estoy de acuerdo con la respuesta de Lamak en cuanto a los cambios al `rank() OVER()`.
2. Hay ciertos elementos de la consulta que no necesitan estar allí, y que agregan confusión.

En particular, no necesitas hacer un `GROUP BY`, ni un `MAX(des.ciclo)`, ni tampoco necesitas la columna `rnk`.

De modo, que para limitarte al objetivo de tu consulta, yo la escribiría de esta manera:

```
select x.*
from (select des.movimiento, des.equipo_identi, des.status, des.ciclo,
        rank() over (partition by des.equipo_identi order by des.ciclo desc, primo.prioridad desc) as rank
      from publico.descarga des 
      inner join publico.prioridad_movimiento primo 
           on des.movimiento = primo.movimiento
     ) x
where rank = 1;
```