# ¿Como puedo seleccionar registros dependiendo del mismo campo con dos valores, pero dándole prioridad a uno?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Tengo la siguiente tabla de MOVIMIENTOS en la que evaluó el campo de estatus, lo que necesito es que cuando exista el campo ESTATUS = 'CONCLUIDO' me ponga solo un registro que pertenece a CONCLUIDO, en caso de que no tenga el estatus 'CONCLUIDO' que proceda a tomar el registro de 'PROCESAR' ya que algunas veces los registros tienen los dos estatus y en otras solo tiene un registro.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En el caso de la imagen los registros sombreados pertenecen al mismo y solo quiero que me muestre el CONCLUIDO pero si no existe el CONCLUIDO que me tome el de PROCESAR.

Comment: El post te puede ayudar un poco [ultimo Movimiento](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/57511/273432)pero puedes leer documentación oficial acerca de CTE

Comment: ¿Podrías compartir la consultas que estás haciendo como código y no como imagen? Por otro lado ¿No veo la columna por la que estás agrupando?

Answer (score 0):

Con WHITE CTE puedes consultar los últimos registros de una tabla suponiendo que hay un Id en la tabla

```
WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT  *,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY HORA DESC) RN
    FROM @MOVIMIENTOS
)
SELECT  TipoCambio,
Concepto,
        HORA,
        Horario,Estatus
FROM CTE
WHERE RN < 2
;
```